# Check if element in array has class and add class if it doesn't - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if an element in an array has a specific class, and if it doesn't, add that class. This is happening when a segment of a pie chart created with chart.js is clicked. When a segment is clicked, a corresponding hidden div should appear, and any unhidden divs should disappear. When the segment is clicked, a class is removed from the relevant div to unhide it, and any unhidden divs should have the class added back to hide it again.

My issue is that I am not sure how to loop through the array to check if any divs don't have the class, and if they don't, to add the class back.

HTML

```
    <div id="mod0" class="m-d-hide">Some content</div>
    <div id="mod1" class="m-d-hide">Some content</div>
    <div id="mod2" class="m-d-hide">Some content</div>
    <div id="mod3" class="m-d-hide">Some content</div>
```

Javascript

```
    var activePoints = window.modulePie1.getElementsAtEvent(event);
    var modDescription = [];
    for(var i=0; i<9; i++) {
       modDescription[i] = document.getElementById("mod"+i);

    if (activePoints.length > 0) {
     var clickedSegmentIndex = activePoints[0]._index;
     if (clickedSegmentIndex==[i]) {
        modDescription[i].classList.remove("m-d-hide");

        //Everything works until here - can't add class

        if (!modDescription.classList.contains("m-d-hide")) {
          modDescription.classList.add("m-d-hide");
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Check `Element.classList.contains(String)`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Just adding the class everywhere without testing first will not harm you. Class lists behave as a Set, so adding an existing class to it won’t duplicate it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Still not 100% sure what you mean. Could you expand a bit further, please?

Comment: @NewMike - ...his point was that if you need the element to have a specific class, just add the class. You don't need to check if the element already has the class, since it can only be added once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix this issue by adding an else statement to the

```
if (clickedSegment==[i])
```

loop, so there was no need to loop through the array and check all the classes.
Code now looks like:

```
    var activePoints = window.modulePie1.getElementsAtEvent(event);
    var modDescription = [];
    for(var i=0; i<9; i++) {
       modDescription[i] = document.getElementById("mod"+i);

    if (activePoints.length > 0) {
     var clickedSegmentIndex = activePoints[0]._index;
     if (clickedSegmentIndex==[i]) {
        modDescription[i].classList.remove("m-d-hide");
       } else {
        if (!modDescription[i].classList.contains("m-d-hide")) {
          modDescription[i].classList.add("m-d-hide");
        }
       }
      }
    }
```